# JAVA use variable in object name

Tags: java, variables

Here is some code of my class:

```
public class update implements ItemListener {

private String TBL;

public void init(String pav, String type) { 
    try {
        this.TBL = type;
        Connection conn = sqlite.ConnectDb();
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TBL+"_imones order by pav asc;");

        pard_reg_imone_choice.removeAll();
        pard_imone_choice.removeAll();

        pard_reg_imone_choice.addItem("VISOS");

        while (rs.next()) {
            pard_reg_imone_choice.addItem(rs.getString("pav"));
            pard_imone_choice.addItem(rs.getString("pav"));
        }

        pard_imone_choice.addItemListener(this);

        rs.close();
```

I need to get something like this:

```
{variable}_reg_imone_choice.removeAll();
{variable}_imone_choice.removeAll();
```

Variable is String type (it's "pirk" and "pard").

Thank you!

Comment: Do you actually have four instances named `pard_reg_imone_choice`, `pirk_reg_imone_choice`, `pard_imone_choice` and `pirk_imone_choice`? (Btw, Java naming conventions uses camel case, you should adopt it as well)

Comment: You probably really want a `Map` instead of hard-coded variable names.

Comment: No I have a class in which I working with choices, labels and other, and I want to get it multiple by sending for class argument "pirk" or "pard" and then it get working by "pirk" or "pard" type.

Comment: I'm aware, and I think your design is bad.

Comment: In Java isn't possibile to use variables in object name.

Comment: could you be more elaborate and give us the context in which you require them

Comment: @Rytis The language "feature" that you are looking for is called HashMap. And even in languages that support such dynamic evaluation of variable names ... it would be wrong to do it that way. Because ... that is what "associate data structures" like HashMap were invented for. Another option is to have different lists; then you just iterate on the list and call "removeAll()" on all the list objects that you put in the "list list" for example. Theoretically, you could use java reflection to access variables by substring searching; but that is ... again: wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the map approach others have suggested the only mechanism I can think of that would give anything like this is reflection

```
Field field = this.getClass().getField(name+"_reg_imone_choice");
Object object = field.get (this);
((List) object).removeAll ();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot interpolate strings into variable names in Java.  Not at runtime.  Not at compile time.  Java variable names must be spelled out in full at compile time.

The closest that you are going to get to this in Java is to use a `Map<String, Choice>` ... something like this:

```
  Map<String, Choice> choices = ... // initialize
  ....
  String prefix = ...
  ....
  choices.get(prefix + "_reg_imone_choice").removeAll();
  choices.get(prefix + "_imone_choice").removeAll();
```

It is also possible to use reflection to do this, provided that the variables are static or instance fields.  (Reflection can't be used to access local variables or method parameters.)

---

However, these solutions go against the grain for an experienced Java programmer, because you introducing various kinds of runtime checking ... and various kinds of unnecessary (IMO) fragility into your code-base.

There is *usually* a better way to do this kind of thing that reveals itself when you start thinking about the problem in the Java way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement if you dont have too many cases

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: "2" is not a valid English word.